# ChangeToken.OnChange not fire on custom configuration provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I'll try to create custom config provider that will take keys from database. As written in manuals, I created this provider and it's work fine. All keys are loaded on start and all works fine.

But now I'm trying to use IOptionsSnapshot and reload keys from db as they change. But nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong? Here is my code:

```
public class EFConfigProvider : ConfigurationProvider
{
    private DateTime lastLoaded;
    public EFConfigProvider(Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> optionsAction)
    {
        OptionsAction = optionsAction;
        lastLoaded = DateTime.Now;
        ChangeToken.OnChange(
            () => Watch(),
            () => {
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                this.Load();
            });
    }

    public new IChangeToken GetReloadToken()
    {
        return Watch();
    }

    Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> OptionsAction { get; }

    // Load config data from EF DB.
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Data.Clear();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ConfigContext>();
        OptionsAction(builder);

        using (var dbContext = new ConfigContext(builder.Options))
        {
            // Save Load Fact
            dbContext.SaveLoadFact();
            // Load Partners Settings
            GetPartners(dbContext);
        }
    }

    private IChangeToken Watch()
    {
        return new DatabaseChangeToken();
    }
}

public class DatabaseChangeToken : IChangeToken
{
    public bool HasChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public bool ActiveChangeCallbacks => false;

    public IDisposable RegisterChangeCallback(Action<object> callback, object state) => EmptyDisposable.Instance;

    internal class EmptyDisposable : IDisposable
    {
        public static EmptyDisposable Instance { get; } = new EmptyDisposable();
        private EmptyDisposable() { }
        public void Dispose() { }
    }
}
```

What I did to start to worked it:

1. I add in class EFConfigProvider variable

```
private ConfigurationReloadToken _reloadToken = new ConfigurationReloadToken();
```

2. I add in constructor

```
// Start Periodic task to refresh the DB
        PeriodicTask.Run(() =>
        {
            //Refresh();
            OnReload();
        }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(reload));
```

3. I Add class for periodTask

```
public class PeriodicTask
{
    public static async Task Run(Action action, TimeSpan period, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(period, cancellationToken);

            if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                action();
        }
    }

    public static Task Run(Action action, TimeSpan period)
    {
        return Run(action, period, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

4. Add method on Reload

```
protected new void OnReload()
        {
            var previousToken = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _reloadToken, new ConfigurationReloadToken());
            previousToken.OnReload();
        }
```

5. Add change of using change token

```
  ChangeToken.OnChange(
                () => { return this._reloadToken; },
                () => {
                    Thread.Sleep(250);
                    this.Load();
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having same requirement and I reached to you code and I tried the same thing and not working.

But your code and some other investigation lead me to the hint.

```
public class CustomConfigurationProvider : ConfigurationProvider
{
    private readonly string applicationName;
    private readonly bool reloadOnChange;
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public CustomConfigurationProvider(string applicationName, bool reloadOnChange)
    {
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
        this.reloadOnChange = reloadOnChange;

        if(reloadOnChange)
        {
        ChangeToken.OnChange(
            () => GetReloadToken(), // listener to token change
            () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                this.Load();
            });
        }
    }

    public override async void Load()
    {
        Data.Clear();

        Data = read data from database;

        if (Condition to check if data in database changed)
        {
            OnReload(); // This will create new token and trigger change so what is register in OnChange above will be called again which is this.Load()
        }
    }
}
```

I also refereed  https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/301/loading-asp-net-core-mvc-views-from-a-database-or-other-location

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/primitives/change-tokens

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks For your answer. I solved it some time ago, but haven't time to write about it.

Yes I used Ichangetoken, but in more primitive ways. I can say that I used it directly.

Comment: OnReload() is not required to be invoked on the initial load - so probably doesn't belong in `Load` method. Probably better off moving OnReload() to be called as part of change token onchange - i.e only when the configuration has been changed from the initial / previous configuration that options monitor is aware of.

Comment: Be careful here: "Data.Clear(); Data = read data from database;". You have a small time interval when you have no configuration at all. This may lead to unpredictable results. Such bugs are very difficult to catch during testing.

Answer (score 5):

*Updated:* I found that overriding `OnReload()` broke the notification of changes (I was using `OptionsMonitor`, which didn't see the changes). So I changed my implementation to not do that. It's calling the default `OnReload()` which handles the notification of changes to `OptionsMonitor`.

---

Your updated implementation really helped me out, so thank you!

But rather than using your custom `PeriodicTask`, you could just use a [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer). The effect is just the same though.

Here is my implementation, which reloads the data every 5 minutes:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

namespace MyProject.Classes.Configuration {
    public class MyConfigProvider : ConfigurationProvider {
        private readonly DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> _dbOptions;
        private readonly Timer _reloadTimer = new Timer();

        public MyConfigProvider(Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> dbOptionsAction) {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
            dbOptionsAction(builder);
            _dbOptions = builder.Options;

            _reloadTimer.AutoReset = false;
            _reloadTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds;
            _reloadTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) => { Load(); };
        }

        public override void Load() {
            try {
                using (var db = new MyDbContext(_dbOptions)) {
                    var settings = db.Settings.AsNoTracking().ToList();
                    Data.Clear();

                    foreach (var s in settings) {
                        Data.Add(s.Name, s.Value);
                    }
                }
                OnReload();
            } finally {
                _reloadTimer.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi,thanks for your code, the `_reloadToken` seems not used, does some code missed the usage or just useless?

Comment: @Panic I guess that's not needed! I checked the project I used this code in, and I had taken it out.